# ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.css'

Tags: angular

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'user-service-client';
}
```

Angular CLI Version : 8.0.6

How to resolve this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.compone
```

Comment: What is your question? [ask]

Comment: How to resolve this error:
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.css'

Comment: It looks correct at the first glance. How did you set up the project? Did you use `ng new`?

Comment: Yes ng new "projectname"

Comment: And if you just start it by `ng serve` you run into this error?

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask a question. You should be providing enough setup/configuration details, research you have done etc so people don't have to ask you a multitude of basic debugging questions. You have to help others help you by outlining  everything you know about the problem. What you have provided so far is completely inadequate

Answer (score 0):

Make sure app.module setup
Or
Module have declaration

Or something wrong inside project structure as per angular guidelines...